# Javascript change font color onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

So I'm trying to change the font color of my entire page when I click on a radio button, like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="textcol" value="#FOF8FF" onclick = "changeText('#FOF8FF');"> Alice Blue<br>
```

Which then calls this function:

```
function changeText(col) 
    {
        console.log(col);
        console.log(document.getElementsByName('boyo'));
        var abc = document.getElementsByName('boyo');
        for(var i = 0, length = abc.length; i < length; i++)
        {
            abc[i].style.color = col;
        }

}
```

And just so you're aware, within all my h3 and p tags (the only text within my document), I give them a name "boyo", like this:

```
<h3 name = "boyo">My favorite food</h3>
```

But for some reason, it does nothing.  I know it has the proper elements (I print them out to console as you can see), and no errors occur, but my font color doesn't change.  What the hell am I doing wrong?

EDIT: When I compare the value of just the string "#80FF08" to the value I pass (which when printed out is also the exact same), it returns FALSE that they're equal - how could this be?  When I manually set the color it works.

Comment: you need to do very very small change  in your code see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995384/javascript-change-font-color-onclick/41995582#41995582

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just set a CSS class on the highest HTML element that defines which `color:...` property is in effect? Why change every individual element's `style` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Your code would work fine if you change the O to 0 in your color Code #FOF8FF

```js
function changeText(col) {
  console.log(col);
  console.log(document.getElementsByName('boyo'));
  var abc = document.getElementsByName('boyo');
  for (var i = 0, length = abc.length; i < length; i++) {
    abc[i].style.color = col;
  }


}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="textcol" value="#FOF8FF" onclick='changeText("#F0F8FF")'>Alice Blue
<br>

<h3 id="colorMe" name="boyo">My favorite food</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the color to other color working correct, seems like `#FOF8FF` is not a valid HEX value :

```js
function changeText(color) {
  console.log(color);
  console.log(document.getElementsByName('boyo'));
  var abc = document.getElementsByName('boyo');
  for (var i = 0, length = abc.length; i < length; i++) {
    abc[i].style.color = color;
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="textcol" value="#FOF8FF" onclick="changeText('#33ccff');">Alice Blue
<br>
<h3 name="boyo">My favorite food</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because #FOF8FF does not exist, try using #000 or any other color in place of #FOF8FF.

If you want to be clear more about it and inspect your element and try to give color: #FOF8FF, It want work either. For your reference I am attaching screen shot of this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`#FOF8FF` doesn't exists change to `O` to `0` and  i added different color code and it's working fine

```js
function changeText(col) 
    {
        console.log(col);
        console.log(document.getElementsByName('boyo')[0]);
        var abc = document.getElementsByName('boyo')[0].style.color = col;
        
        

}
```

```html
<h3 name = "boyo">My favorite food</h3>
       <input type="radio" name="textcol" value="#d2d2d2" onclick = "changeText('#d2d2d2');"> Alice Blue<br>
```